# IntelliJ editor plugin implement - jtextpane is not editable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-plugin

I am implementing an IntelliJ plugin. My code inherits FileEditor, and when I open a file in `.md` format, it will create a multi-line JTextPane to take input from the user.

I have succeeded in printing multiple JTextPane. As I intended, when multiple JTextPane are displayed on the screen and if there is a margin, they are displayed glued on top.

However, when I run my code, it outputs several `asdf` strings, but they are not editable. help.

```
public class MyEditor implements FileEditor {
    List<Block> list = new LinkedList<>();
    Box interiorPanel = Box.createVerticalBox();
    JPanel wrapper = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(wrapper);

    public MyEditor(Project project, VirtualFile file) {
        wrapper.add(interiorPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
            Block block = new Block();
            block.setText("asdf");
            block.setEditable(true);
            list.add(block);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public @NotNull JComponent getComponent() {
        for(JTextPane elem : list){
            elem.setEditable(true);
            interiorPanel.add(elem);
        }

        return scrollPane;
    }

    ...
```

Block is simply an inheritance from JTextPane.

```
public class Block extends JTextPane {
    // nothing here yet
}
```

[Output image in IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh6Uk.png)

The execution result is as shown in the picture above. They are note editable.

I tried running the same code in Java to see if there was a problem with the use of the swing component, and it's output fine there. As shown in the picture below, the cursor is displayed well, and the text can be edited here.

[Output image in Java Swing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA65p.png)

I don't know why this difference occurs. Please help me...